# Google chart - columns labels

Tags: php, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I have following code:

```
$rows = array(); 
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Charging Current', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Battery Voltage', 'type' => 'number'),    
    array('label' => 'Charging Power', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Rotation', 'type' => 'number'),
);
```

and wonder how to change it, to be able to change the number of columns. Display columns, depending on the variables (something like this):

```
$rows = array(); 
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
   array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
if ($current == "true") {**
    array('label' => 'Charging Current', 'type' => 'number'),
}
if ($voltage == "true") {
    array('label' => 'Battery Voltage', 'type' => 'number'),    
}
if ($power == "true") {
    array('label' => 'Charging Power', 'type' => 'number'),
}
if ($rotation == "true") {
    array('label' => 'Rotation', 'type' => 'number'),
}
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $temp = array();
    // the following line will be used to slice the chart
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['TimeStamp']); 

    // Values of each slice
    if ($current == "true") {
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['ChargingCurrent']); 
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }
    if ($voltage == "true") {
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['BatteryVoltage']); 
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);  
    }
    if ($power == "true") {
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['ChargingPower']); 
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }
    if ($rotation == "true") {
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Rotation']); 
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);  
    }
}
```

I hope is clear what I try to do. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can easily add an item to your `$tables['col']` array. To add something to an array do this:

`$table['cols'][] = 'something';`

In your case, your code would looks something like this:

```
$rows = array();
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string')
);

if ($current == "true") {
    $table['cols'][] = array('label' => 'Charging Current', 'type' => 'number');
}
if ($voltage == "true") {
    $table['cols'][] = array('label' => 'Battery Voltage', 'type' => 'number');
}
if ($power == "true") {
    $table['cols'][] = array('label' => 'Charging Power', 'type' => 'number');
}
if ($rotation == "true") {
    $table['cols'][] = array('label' => 'Rotation', 'type' => 'number');
}
);
```

Comment: Ha ha, I just realized you are doing the exact same thing in your code below for the rows.  I'm pretty sure you can do the exact same thing for the columns.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean...?

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I needed.
I use php only time to time to connect some projects and I couldn't figure out how to solve that issue.